# Code-behind free, using Data-trigger for updating/resizing GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, gridviewcolumn

Im trying, using Code-behind-FREE XAML-code, to resize `GridViewColumn / column1` each time `Button1` is pressed according to the newly brought data (Button1 should bring new data and resize `column1` of the ListView at the same time, the code that updates the data is not written down here).

when executing no error appears, but the size of `column1` wont change, even i try to send dump values instead of `auto`, like `100`,  to see if it changes it size, which means im not reaching the right value!

How can i reach  width value of column1 in the Setter ? will this method work eventually or is another method necessary?

i've written a fully functional Code-Behind but now i have to do the analog-Code-behind-FREE due to MVVM-reasons, for comparison und reference you'll find it after the XAML code!

Thanks in Advance!

XAML-Code

```
     <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="dataGridView1">     
                <GridView.Columns >
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="column1" >
                        <ContentControl>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers> 
                                   <!--the resize will happen here by triggering using the button-->
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True"> 
                                        <Setter Property="GridViewColumn.Width" Value="auto" /> 
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsPressed}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="GridViewColumn.Width" Value="auto" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>                        
                        </ContentControl>
```

Code-behind-version (works fine, but must use the code-behind-FREE version!)

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
foreach (GridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    c.Width = 0; // Breite = 0
    c.Width = double.NaN; // Resize 
}
 }
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the `Output Window`? I don't think that you can use `GridViewColumn.width` as the property name. First, you'd need a capital `W` for `Width` (just use that as the property) and you're better off using `GridViewColumn` as the `Style.TargetType` property value.

Comment: ive changed to GridViewColumn.Width instead of GridViewColumn.width as said, no errors appear not but its still not working (ive updated the text above)!

if i just use Width not GridViewColumn.Width ill get another error (Style Property "width" can not be dissolved, make sure the used the Targetype is from Style, or use Class.property-Syntax )

Comment: Ok, so that's not a problem then. The other thing that can help is to use the `ActualWidth` property instead of `Width`.